# Spacing between columns in the amsmath's cases environment

Tags: spacing, amsmath, best-practices

As most of you may already know, the `amsmath` package provides a `cases` environment. As the example in [the user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) indicates, the typical usage of the environment is to construct a formula with different values in different conditions. Its implementation says an em quad is inserted between the columns:

```
\renewenvironment{cases}{%
  \matrix@check\cases\env@cases
}{%
  \endarray\right.%
}
\def\env@cases{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}%
}
```

On the other hand, [Mathematics into Type](http://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/mit-2.pdf) says in Section 3.1.6b that two-em quad is used

> Between a symbolic statement and a condition on the statement.

and the example is

[image: example of qquad]

```
\[
  x^n - y^n - z^n = A \qquad (n = 0, 1, \dotsc, p).
\]
```

I think this is the case which the `cases` environment should fall under, but `\quad` instead of `\qquad` is used as noted above. This is confusing me.

Which spacing is better from the AMS viewpoint? Are there other references mentioning these situations?

Comment: What does this have to do with (La)TeX? If you're referring to style, then I'm sure [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) will provide the style required or suggested by the AMS. Either way, this question seems to solicit opinion-based answers, and is therefore off topic.

Comment: @Werner Since Mathematics into Type is copyrighted/licensed by the AMS, I thought the rules in this book are their official opinions at the time of publishing at least. That's why I opened this question; I'm not asking "hi everyone, which one do you prefer?", but wondering why there is a difference between the book and `amsmath.sty` and if this could be a potential discrepancy unless the rules are updated.

Comment: As it stands you're asking "which spacing is better" which is generally subjective (even though you request a response specific from AMS). Perhaps it would be more appropriate to ask this question to the AMS directly. @barbarabeeton?

Comment: this does seem to be a contradiction.  i will investigate.  however, the question is out of scope for this forum, as pointed out already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `cases` environment was originally defined with the commands
`\cases ... \endcases` in `amstex`, and later converted to latex syntax
in `amsmath`.  so for the answer, one has to look at the history.

i didn't find any explicit commentary on the choice of one quad vs. two,
but there are other resources available.

a senior copyeditor, who trained under ellen swanson (author of *math into type*)
said that if the condition starts with a word -- which the conditions on `cases`
often do -- then a double quad is too much.  a single quad is sufficient in that
situation.

so i checked the published documentation in *joy of tex*.  in the first edition,
the example for `\cases` has a double quad:

[image: output of example code]

however, in the second edition, this has been reduced to a single quad:

[image]

(that does look much better.)

this is the equivalent of how `cases` is defined in `amsmath`.

other examples of math with a condition -- with "raw" math, no words -- do
use the double quad as shown in section 3.1.6b of *math into type*.

Comment: Thank you for your investigation. So in summary, the rule is to use 1) `\quad` for conditions starting with natural language, and 2) `\qquad` for the ones starting with mathematical expression?

Comment: @yudai-nkt -- yes; single quad before conditions starting with a word and double quad before the ones starting with a math expression.  if a condition within `cases` starts with a bare math expression, then a `\quad` can be added after the longest expression on the left, before the `&`.  (maybe this should be added to the documentation; i'll take a look.)