# How can I change the default space between columns in case environment?

Tags: amsmath, cases

Building off of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383978/spacing-between-columns-in-the-amsmaths-cases-environment), I would like to change the default space between the two columns of the amsmath `cases` environment to be a `\qquad` rather than a `quad`. I tried just copying the code on that question and changing the `\quad`, but I receive the error message:

Package amsmath Error: Old form `\matrix' should be \begin{matrix}. ^^I^^I\begin{cases}

Is there a way to make this global change?

edit: I've tried changing `\matrix` to `\begin{matrix}` and adding `\end{matrix}` in various places, but no dice.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Please post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem.  To answer your question we need to know what document class and packges you want to use.

Comment: The code you are referring to has @s in their names did you remember to add `\makeatletter... \makeatother` around that code? My guess, you did not and thus the `\matrix@...` line was interpreted as `\matrix ` and then @... Next time please post a full minimal example so we know exactly what you are doing and can test it ourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `latexdef -p amsmath cases` you get

```latex
\cases:
\long macro:->\matrix@check \cases \env@cases
```

Well, for historical reasons, one needs to look at `\env@cases`

```latex
\env@cases:
macro:->\let \@ifnextchar \new@ifnextchar \left \lbrace \def \arraystretch {1.2}\array {@{}l@{\quad }l@{}}
```

Good! There's just one `\quad`!

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \patchcmd

\makeatletter % we need to patch \env@cases that has @ in its name
\patchcmd{\env@cases}{\quad}{\qquad}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{cases}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The output without the patch would be

[image]